# Detect a race condition in imported package

Tags: go, race-condition

I have package where I write a `golang` code.
I have a fear that program works incorrecly because it outputs different results from time to time. Probably it's due to `race condtions`. So I run multiple times:

```
go run -race myprogram
```

But I didn't got any warning or errros.

Probably, errors are in another package I imported. As I understand, `-race` flag doesn't detect them. If so, how can I do it (detect race condtion which occurs not in my code but in package I imported and I use in my code)?

Comment: The race detector detects data races when they happen in your program, not just in the `main` package.

Comment: @JimB if so it is very good.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The race condition detection is false negative rather than false positive. This means that it detects race at any time when it has just happened - when a program tries to read or write a shared value at the same time. The bottom line is the -race flag works not at 100% cases.